# Parsing Scheme using Scala parser combinators

Tags: parsing, scala

I'm writing a small scheme interpreter in Scala and I'm running into problems parsing lists in Scheme. My code parses lists that contain multiple numbers, identifiers, and booleans, but it chokes if I try to parse a list containing multiple strings or lists. What am I missing?

Here's my parser:

```
class SchemeParsers extends RegexParsers {

// Scheme boolean #t and #f translate to Scala's true and false
def bool : Parser[Boolean] = 
    ("#t" | "#f") ^^ {case "#t" => true; case "#f" => false}

// A Scheme identifier allows alphanumeric chars, some symbols, and 
// can't start with a digit
def id : Parser[String] = 
    """[a-zA-Z=*+/<>!\?][a-zA-Z0-9=*+/<>!\?]*""".r ^^ {case s => s}

// This interpreter only accepts numbers as integers
def num : Parser[Int] = """-?\d+""".r ^^ {case s => s toInt}

// A string can have any character except ", and is wrapped in "
def str : Parser[String] = '"' ~> """[^""]*""".r <~ '"' ^^ {case s => s}

// A Scheme list is a series of expressions wrapped in ()
def list : Parser[List[Any]] = 
    '(' ~> rep(expr) <~ ')' ^^ {s: List[Any] => s}

// A Scheme expression contains any of the other constructions
def expr : Parser[Any] = id | str | num | bool | list ^^ {case s => s}
}
```

Comment: How do you handle whitespace?

Comment: Why do you need `^^ {case s => s}` ?

Comment: @MJP +1 , `^^ {case s => s}` can be removed

Comment: @Gabe One would presume that `RegexParsers` default handling of whitespace is in force.

Comment: Failing test cases would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was correctly pointed out by @Gabe, you left some white-spaces unhandled:

```
scala> object SchemeParsers extends RegexParsers {
     |
     | private def space  = regex("[ \\n]*".r)
     |
     | // Scheme boolean #t and #f translate to Scala's true and false
     | private def bool : Parser[Boolean] =
     |     ("#t" | "#f") ^^ {case "#t" => true; case "#f" => false}
     |
     | // A Scheme identifier allows alphanumeric chars, some symbols, and
     | // can't start with a digit
     | private def id : Parser[String] =
     |     """[a-zA-Z=*+/<>!\?][a-zA-Z0-9=*+/<>!\?]*""".r
     |
     | // This interpreter only accepts numbers as integers
     | private def num : Parser[Int] = """-?\d+""".r ^^ {case s => s toInt}
     |
     | // A string can have any character except ", and is wrapped in "
     | private def str : Parser[String] = '"' ~> """[^""]*""".r <~ '"' <~ space ^^ {case s => s}
     |
     | // A Scheme list is a series of expressions wrapped in ()
     | private def list : Parser[List[Any]] =
     |     '(' ~> space  ~> rep(expr) <~ ')' <~ space ^^ {s: List[Any] => s}
     |
     | // A Scheme expression contains any of the other constructions
     | private def expr : Parser[Any] = id | str | num | bool | list ^^ {case s => s}
     |
     | def parseExpr(str: String) = parse(expr, str)
     | }
defined module SchemeParsers   

scala> SchemeParsers.parseExpr("""(("a" "b") ("a" "b"))""")
res12: SchemeParsers.ParseResult[Any] = [1.22] parsed: List(List(a, b), List(a, b))

scala> SchemeParsers.parseExpr("""("a" "b" "c")""")
res13: SchemeParsers.ParseResult[Any] = [1.14] parsed: List(a, b, c)

scala> SchemeParsers.parseExpr("""((1) (1 2) (1 2 3))""")
res14: SchemeParsers.ParseResult[Any] = [1.20] parsed: List(List(1), List(1, 2), List(1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! I thought the Regex parser handled whitespace for me, but I see I was mistaken.

Comment: `RegexParsers` skip space automatically at the beginning of any literal string or regular expression. I wonder if the problem is related to the `Char` being used...

Comment: @stomcavage `RegexParsers` does handle space for you, just not with `Char`.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem with the code is your usage of characters instead of strings. Below, I removed the redundant `^^ { case s => s }` and replaced all characters with strings. I'll further discuss this issue below.

```
class SchemeParsers extends RegexParsers {

// Scheme boolean #t and #f translate to Scala's true and false
def bool : Parser[Boolean] = 
    ("#t" | "#f") ^^ {case "#t" => true; case "#f" => false}

// A Scheme identifier allows alphanumeric chars, some symbols, and 
// can't start with a digit
def id : Parser[String] = 
    """[a-zA-Z=*+/<>!\?][a-zA-Z0-9=*+/<>!\?]*""".r ^^ {case s => s}

// This interpreter only accepts numbers as integers
def num : Parser[Int] = """-?\d+""".r ^^ {case s => s toInt}

// A string can have any character except ", and is wrapped in "
def str : Parser[String] = "\"" ~> """[^""]*""".r <~ "\""

// A Scheme list is a series of expressions wrapped in ()
def list : Parser[List[Any]] = 
    "(" ~> rep(expr) <~ ")" ^^ {s: List[Any] => s}

// A Scheme expression contains any of the other constructions
def expr : Parser[Any] = id | str | num | bool | list
}
```

All `Parsers` have an implicit `accept` for their `Elem` types. So, if the basic element is a `Char`, such as in `RegexParsers`, then there's an implicit accept action for them, which is what happens here for the symbols `(`, `)` and `"`, which are characters in your code.

What `RegexParsers` do automatically is to skip white spaces (defined as `protected val whiteSpace = """\s+""".r`, so you could override that) automatically at the beginning of any `String` or `Regex`. It also takes care of moving the positioning cursor past the white space in case of error messages.

One consequence of this that you seem not to have realized is that `" a string beginning with a space"` will have its prefix space removed from the parsed output, which is very unlikely to be something you want. :-)

Also, since `\s` includes new lines, a new line will be acceptable before any identifier, which may or may not be what you want.

You may disable space skipping in your regex as a whole by overrideing `skipWhiteSpace`. On the other hand, the default `skipWhiteSpace` tests for `whiteSpace`'s length, so you could potentially turn it on and off just by manipulating the value of `whiteSpace` throughout the parsing process.